# Strange iPhone application icon view in the iTunes's Applications section

Tags: iphone, graphics, icons, itunes

When I drag 'My iPhone App' application's file into iTunes it has proper view. Rounded corners and transparent background.

Then I close iTunes and open it again. Corners are still rounded but... What has happened with the background?

[image]
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/15fee337bc.png

Icon is a project's resource file named 'iTunesArtwork' with dimension 512x512, PNG format.

Answer (score 0):

The icon needs to be 57x57 png. Not 512x512.

Comment: Please don't mix up application icon (which should have name 'Icon.png' and dimension 57x57) with icon that identifies application in iTunes when it built for ad-hoc distribution. I have both.
And also I have read this: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in iTunes. Try to update to latest one.

Comment: I've made the same conclusion. I have tried the issue on other applications - the same problem. So... Looks like a bug in iTunes.